# Object doesn't support #inspect with many to many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many

I have this problem already a week and I cannot google it anymore. I'm stuck.
I have a simple model Game:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data, :history

  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  TIMES_PER_MOVE = [1,2,3,4,5]
  TIMES_PER_GAME = [5, 10, 15, 30]

  has_and_belongs_to_many :players, class_name: User

  def create_available(user)
    self.players << user
    self.save!
  end

end
```

And a model User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :settings, Hash

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, :country, :birth_date, :password, :security_code, :invitation_token
  attr_writer :current_step


  has_and_belongs_to_many :games
  ...
end
```

I create association between them with join table:

```
create_table :games_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :game
end
```

Everything looks good? -- NO WAY!!!

When I create an instance of Game :

```
def create
    @game = Game.new()

      respond_to do |format|
        if @game.create_available(current_user) # see this method in the model
          format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: 'Game was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @game, status: :created, location: @game }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end    
  end
```

It says Ok) that's fine. I created a game! BUT!!! What is going on in the console:

```
>> Game.all
  Game Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `games`.* FROM `games` 
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

AND

```
>> u  = User.find_by_id 1
u  = User.find_by_id 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
#<User id: 1, last_name: "Ivanyshyn", first_name: "Ostap", password:...>

>> u.games
u.games
  Game Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `games`.* FROM `games` INNER JOIN `games_users` ON `games`.`id` = `games_users`.`game_id` WHERE `games_users`.`user_id` = 1
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

When I try to do in my view something like this:

```
= current_user.not_started_games.each do |game|
  = game.time_per_move
```

My browser give something I would have never expected to see(I even do not use anywhere :history symbol!!!!):

```
undefined method `new' for :history:Symbol
```

This problem makes me cry. Maybe I am creating game instance incorrectly? Or my association is bad?

Comment: Don't cry. Post to SO and we'll fix it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data, :history
                   ^^^^^^^^
```

Serialize is defined as:

```
serialize(attr_name, class_name = Object)
```

..it does not take multiple serializable arguments. 
See:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize

What you probably meant to do is this:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data 
  serialize :history
```